# Problem with Kontena Lens and Snap

Tags: snap

I was trying to install Kontena Lens from snap, have run this command:

```
sudo snap install kontena-lens --classic
```

It installed but the app wasn't opening. I tried to reinstall it, didn't help. Downloaded manually snap file from lens website, run this command:

```
sudo snap install Lens-5.2.5-latest.20211001.2.amd64.snap --dangerous --classic
```

It installed, but it didn't help.  I'm trying to lunch the app from the icon (when you open right bottom menu), as usual apps. Thought maybe I should run it from my console with sudo, wrote

```
sudo lens
```

but it didn't help, instead of that I got this input:

```
/root/Desktop was removed, reassigning DESKTOP to homedir
/root/Downloads was removed, reassigning DOWNLOAD to homedir
/root/Templates was removed, reassigning TEMPLATES to homedir
/root/Public was removed, reassigning PUBLICSHARE to homedir
/root/Documents was removed, reassigning DOCUMENTS to homedir
/root/Music was removed, reassigning MUSIC to homedir
/root/Pictures was removed, reassigning PICTURES to homedir
/root/Videos was removed, reassigning VIDEOS to homedir
```

Did something bad happened? Do I need to change something now and how do I fix Lens problem? My Ubuntu version: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Experienced this problem and here is how I solved it.

From my experience, this issue happened to me twice while using the snap installed lens both on Ubuntu 18 and 22.
So my solution was to remove the one installed via snap and install a downloaded one in `.deb` format

1. Uninstall the snap lens snap package

```sh
sudo snap remove kontena-lens
```

2. Download the `.deb` file from official lens website  [Lens](https://k8slens.dev/). From the dropdown select Linux X64(.deb). Even `.rpm` still works fine
3. Proceed to the location where it was installed and run the following command

```sh
ls | grep -iF lens | xargs sudo dpkg -i
```

That should fix your problem.

> Recently Lens requires you to create an account. Just use your browser to create a Free account and enjoy Lens